# import of a vue.js component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Hello i have a problem for import a component in a exercice on vue.js.

[Here is the architecture of my files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru2Fu.png)

I am in the CarPage.vue and i want to import CarList.vue and CarDetails.vue.

Here is the part of code with my import:

```js
<script>
import CarList from '../components/CarList.vue'
import CarDetails from '../components/CarDetails.vue'
export default {
    components: {CarList, CarDetails}
}
</script>
```

i have this error:

```js
Failed to compile.

./src/components/pages/CarPage.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/pages/CarPage.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/CarDetails.vue' in 'C:\Users\rollivier\Desktop\Franck\dicolor\vue\medium\src\components\pages'
```

Comment: CarList and CarDetails seem to be in the folder one up from where CarPage is ... so ... `../CarList.vue`?

Comment: Failed to compile.

./src/components/pages/CarPage.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/pages/CarPage.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/CarDetails.vue' in 'C:\Users\rollivier\Desktop\Franck\dicolor\vue\medium\src\components\pages'

Comment: nevermind ... see edited comment (errors should go in the question, not in a comment where they are impossible to read)

Comment: sorry i have edit that

Comment: as I said, nevermind, see edited first comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CarPage.vue` is sitting in the same components file. So you need to import as such :

```
<script>
import CarList from '../CarList.vue'
import CarDetails from '../CarDetails.vue'
export default {
    components: {CarList, CarDetails}
}
</script>
```